# Retrive WooCommerce Category name by WooCommerce Category ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I have been searching and found a function that will display all WooCommerce product categories, but I am looking for a function that will retrieve single product category name by giving product category ID. Raw product category name, no url, no thumbnail, nothing.

I need to use it in my template file.

For instance:
Category Name for 'Bags' has id '15'

I need something like this:

showCategoryName(15);

RESULT:  Bags

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP native functions like get_terms:

```
function woocommerceCategoryName($id){
    $term = get_term( $id, 'product_cat' );
    return $term->name;        
}
```